# Mongoose QueryStream and Request Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, node-request

When performing a QueryStream on a Model such as

```
User.find({}).stream().on('data', (user) => {
    request.post(someOptions, (error, response, body) => {
         if(!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
             user.someProperty = body.newValue;
             user.save((err) => {
                 if (err) console.log(err)
             });
         } else {
             console.log(error);
             console.log(response);
         }
}).on('end', () => {
    console.log('all users have new values');
});
```

I'm receiving the console output for the end event and then receiving an error:

```
all users have new values
TypeError: user.save is not a function
    at Request._callback
```

I'm assuming this means that the request.post function is running one too many times, as I tried to do this without a stream and simply a

```
.find({} (err, users) => {
     for(user in users) {
         request.post...
     } 
});
```

but this was returning a bad status code from the api I'm posting to as `request.post()` was sending an `undefined` value in the options I'm passing that I get from the user document, even though all the documents do have defined values. Although, I wasn't receiving a error for save not being a function.

Can anyone shed some light on what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified version assuming you don't need `stream` (which should be swapped out for `cursor`) and you have `request-promise-native` available

```
const users = await User.find().exec()
for(let user of users) {
    const body = await request.post(someOptions)
    if(body) {
        user.someProperty = body.newValue
        await user.save()
    }
}
```

From the code it looks like you're making the same `post` and updating the same value of every `user`. If that is the case, why not:

```
const body = await request.post(someOptions)
if(body) {
    await User.update(
      { },
      { $set: { someProperty: body.newValue } },
      { multi: true }
    )
}
```

Comment: Every user has a unique property that I'm sending in the post options so the second solution wouldn't work, but that first solution is nice, didn't know about request-promise-native, thank you